# Visiting another terminal during 10-hour layover at CDG

Tags: transit, cdg

My son is arriving at Terminal 2E and departing from Terminal 2E at Charles de Gaulle. He has a 10-hour layover. Will he be able to go to terminal 2C?

Comment: What citizenship are they holding? And what terminal are you referring 2C? 2G?

Comment: What do you mean by "go to terminal"? enter the checkins?

Answer (score 1):

It wasn't clear from your original post whether you meant 2C or 2G. And whether you meant airside or landside. Assuming airside:

For the latter that's a no. There's no airside connection between 2G and the rest of CDG.

For 2C, the blue shuttle connects most terminals in T2 and T1 (except 2G). Whether your son would be allowed inside, and back to 2E, I have no idea. I don't see why not but I haven't been to CDG in close to 4 years, so can't say for sure.

[image]

Comment: 2G is connected to 2F through the [orange shuttle](https://www.parisaeroport.fr/passagers/acces/paris-charles-de-gaulle/navettes-inter-terminaux), but since it's mainly a Schengen terminal, I doubt they'd be able to get it without entering Schengen

Comment: Some airports will only allow passengers with a flight departing from a given terminal to enter that terminal (either for security reasons or just to avoid people getting lost). Others will allow any passenger anywhere. Others still will have rules somewhere in between like "we'll let you into another terminal only if there's more than X hours before your flight". Not sure what the situation is in CDG, but IIRC from another question (not personal experience), the airside shuttle is pre-security, so one may be able to take the bus and then be rejected at security at the "wrong" terminal.

Comment: One can walk (landside) between 2A-B-C-D-E-F, you only go through security once there.